# Can i change the order of participle clause of "a reason for the action in the main clause" without effecting the meaning

Tags: american-english, clauses

OP's participle clause "Having nothing left to do , paula went home = Since paula had nothing left to do,she went home"

would the meaning not be different if i change it into "paula went home ,having nothing to do"? or it's my preference whether i precede it or not,right?

another example:" i gave him a bunch of flowers , thinking he will like me more" Does it euqual "thinking he will like me more , i gave him a bunch of flowers

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of

> Having nothing left to do, Paula went home.

is the same as

> Because she had nothing left to do, Paula went home.

You can change places of the clause in the latter sentence to get

> Paula went home because she had nothing left to do.

(notice there is no comma there) and then turn the subordinate clause into a participle clause again:

> Paula went home, having nothing left to do.

So, the answer is, yes, for participle clauses of the type "a reason for the action in the main clause" you can.